# What is the difference between "skills", "abilities", and "talents"?

Tags: differences, synonyms

Are there differences in meaning of the words "skills", "abilities", and "talents" within the context of describing what a person can do?

Comment: Please check definitions and usage examples. If you still have micro-level questions, do try ELL.

Comment: meta: Whatever has happened to the GR option?

Comment: @Kris It's under OT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding:

- *skill* — something learnt by putting in conscious effort
- *talent* — something natural in a person (probably learnt unconsciously)
- *ability* — capacity to do things (a measure of skill or talent)

Answer (score 0):

A basketball player can be skilled (experience and training) and/or talented (natural ability) to finish the game on behalf of his team (ability).